# What's wrong with my syntax about filter date

Tags: mysql

I want to filter my database into data where it happens in month 4/5/6 and in month 7/8/9, here's my syntax :

```
select
    buyer_id,
    tgl
from data_2017
where
    month(tgl) = 4 or month(tgl) = 5 or month(tgl) = 6 AND
    buyer_id IN (select buyer_id, tgl from data_2017
                 here month(tgl) = 7 or month(tgl) = 8 or month(tgl) = 9);
```

and I don't know which one is wrong with this syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you have a predence issue involving missing parentheses in the `WHERE` clause.  Your current logic is actually doing this:

```
WHERE
    MONTH(tgl) = 4 OR MONTH(tgl) = 5 OR (MONTH(tgl) = 6 AND buyer_id IN (... subquery))
```

You should put parentheses around the month checks, to evaluate them together. 
 But, in addition to fixing this, I would probably also write your query using a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d1.buyer_id,
    d1.tgl
FROM data_2017 d1
INNER JOIN data_2017 d2
    ON d1.buyer_id = d2.buyer_id
WHERE
    MONTH(d1.tgl) IN (4, 5, 6) AND
    MONTH(d2.tgl) IN (7, 8, 9);
```

Comment: sorry im still new in mysql, what is d2? there is only 1 table i use in this syntax

Comment: thankyou for your response, but i've tried your syntax and it was wrong, it became more than 35k data, in this case it became buyer who transaction in 4 until 7 appear, but what i want is like example there's buyer in month 4 and do transaction again in month 7 is then the data should appear, but when the buyer only transaction in month 4 or month 7, the data should not be appear

Comment: Try using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead.  If that still doesn't generate what you want, then it is time for you to add sample input/output to your question.  _Show_ us the result you want here.

Comment: ok, like this, the example was like, if i do the transaction between month 4/5/6 and i do transaction again in between month 7/8/9 then the i become in that data, but if only do transaction in month 4/5/6 or month 7/8/9 then i should not appear in that data.

Comment: Honestly, my query is already using this logic.  Again, you should add sample data if the answers given here still don't resolved your problem.

Comment: WHERE
    MONTH(d1.tgl) IN (4, 5, 6) AND
    MONTH(d2.tgl) IN (7, 8, 9);

but in your query when i try to launch it, it became the buyer who do the transaction only in month 4/5/6 also appear in my data

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil For reference, next time you ask a SQL or other data-related question on this site, please consider adding sample input and output.  This greatly reduces the amount of uncertainty and iterating you would have to do with someone who posts an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is tgl data type DATE? Using month on the column in search condition will prevent mysql using indexes. If it is of DATE, you can change the query:

```
select
    buyer_id,
    tgl
from data_2017
where tgl between '2017-04-01' and '2017-06-30'
and buyer_id in (SELECT DISTINCT buyer_id FROM tgl between '2017-07-01' and '2017-09-30')
```

Comment: How do you know which year(s) the OP actually wants here?

Comment: i've tried this syntax but it was interupted, but thankyouu sir

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want whatever buyer_id exists in month 7/8/9 to lookup 4/5/6 data. The following is a modified version of your current query:

```
SELECT
      buyer_id,
      tgl
FROM  data_2017
WHERE MONTH(tgl) IN (4,5,6) 
AND   buyer_id IN (SELECT buyer_id FROM data_2017
                   WHERE  MONTH(tgl) IN (7,8,9) GROUP BY buyer_id);
```

Comment: thankyou sir for your response, but idk why the data appear in only month 5, it's seems any wrong but idk what the wrong is

Comment: The `GROUP BY` in your subquery is confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , I think maybe if the `buyer_id` exists more than once in month 7,8,9, shouldn't it be grouped so that each `buyer_id` only appear once during `IN`? Or maybe I misunderstood the question.... again..

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil , can you run the subquery alone and see how many `buyer_id` result?

Comment: i've run your query and the result was only 49 which is the amount for buyer_id who only do transaction in month 5. i dont understand why this is happen, i was agree with your query too but this mysql i dont understand why gonna be like this

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil if like that, you should do what Tim's suggest earlier; provide some data sample from your table `data_2017` update it into your question. You can find the `Edit` link under the `mysql` tag in your question above.

Comment: idk how to insert my table in here (data_2017)